# Permutation matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

Write the permutation matrix $P_{\pi}$ for the next permutations:
$$
P= \pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5\\2 &3 &1 &5 &4}
$$
What is $\det (P_{\pi})$ without really calculating it?

Comment: Is is homework? What do you know about permutation matrices?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and give some details on what you mean by "next permutations" ?

Comment: I don't have a 3rd row. It says: write the permutation matrix which corresponds to the permutations listed in P.

Comment: As given here, $P$ describes _one_ permutation, namely the one that maps 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 1, 4 to 5 and 5 to 4. In cycle notation (if you're more familiar with that) it would be $P=(1\;2\;3)(4\;5)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "permutation matrix" associated to $\pi$ is the matrix that is obtained from the identity matrix by "swapping columns" according to the permutation $\pi$.

For example, if 
$$\pi = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4
\end{array}\right),$$
then the permutation matrix would be the matrix obtained from the identity by moving the first column to the 2nd column position; the second column to the third column position; the third column to the first column position; and leaving the fourth column in the fourth column position. That is,
$$P_{\pi}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).$$

Because $P_{\pi}$ is obtained from the identity by swapping columns, its determinant will be either $1$ or $-1$; it is $1$ if you performed an even number of column exchanges/swaps, and $-1$ if you performed an odd number of column/swaps exchanges.

How does the parity of the number of column exchanges/swaps relate to $\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do you know the [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) of the permutation?

What's more, for finding the determinant of a matrix, instead of *calculating* it by definition, people usually use the *properties* of the determinant. Have you written down your $P_{\pi}$? Do you see how can one get $P_{\pi}$ by the identity matrix?

Comment: Can you please write down the Ppi?

Comment: @Andrew: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix